# Reference request: Vector bundles and line bundles etc.

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

I am interested in learning algebraic geometry and I talked to one of my professors today (who is, in part, an algebraic geometer) and he recommended I understand the analytic analogue of the ideas in algebraic geometry so it's not just abstract nonsense when I first see it. Some of specific words he mentioned were vector bundles and line bundles but he could not give any recommendations on the spot and recommended that I ask here.

There are only two sources that I know of which cover these subjects in a way that I think coincide with my relatively modest understanding of mathematics (which I will cover a bit later) are the first part of Hatcher's book on K-theory and Spivak's Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry although the latter will, admittedly, cover much more than I need or could handle at the moment. If there are any more differential geometry concepts of which I should be aware as well, please feel free to include that as well. I am also aware that I will need to know some commutative algebra and complex analysis and I have gotten some solid recommendations on those topics (some from here, in fact).

These are the courses I've taken which I think are relevant to recommendations (all courses are undergraduate): algebra, analysis 1/advanced calculus, differential geometry, proof-based linear algebra, and I am familiar with some topology (in that I know what a topological space is and what a fundamental group is. I will definitely study that more over the summer), I did a reading course on algebraic curves covering the first three chapters of Fulton plus the proof of Bézout's theorem, and I have done an almost reading course in geometry/topology so I am aware of what manifolds are and some of the relevant topology.

Comment: Claire Voisin has a very nice two part book about complex algebraic geometry, I only have the first part but it is great.

Comment: Dear Brendan, I think that the first two volumes of Spivak are well worth reading if you don't know differential geometry/topology (and related topics) already.  On the other hand, Miles Reid's *Undergraduate algebraic geometry* is an excellent entry point to algebraic geometry, which doesn't need very much background, and is not at all abstract.  Regards,

Answer (score 11):

Bott and Tu's *Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology*. (This has a lot of other stuff too, but it's all stuff that you'll need analogues of in algebraic geometry.)

Comment: +1. One of the all time great mathematics textbooks on any subject.

Comment: I've also heard that this is a fantastic book. However, I'm afraid my topology may not quite be up to scratch since I assume it's quite a topology heavy book so I don't know if I can just dive right into it. How much topology am I going to have to know to be able to read it?

Comment: If I remember right, you really just need point-set topology and the definition of a smooth manifold.

Answer (score 10):

Milnor and Stasheff's book "Characteristic Classes" has a lot of foundational material on vector bundles.

Answer (score 10):

John Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* has a good chapter on vector bundles.  You may also want to check out Morita's *Geometry of Differential Forms* to see characteristic classes in the de Rham framework (which will probably be easier given your background than the more abstract, algebraic topological definitions of characteristic classes).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your background, I think you would enjoy reading *[Principles of Algebraic geometry](http://books.google.ca/books/about/Principles_of_Algebraic_Geometry.html?id=Sny48qKdW40C)* by Griffiths and Harris.

Comment: Maybe for a second reference but I think this is a very difficult and terse text to self learn from without a lot of graduate level work.