# Gentle introduction to fibre bundles and gauge connections

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory

To better understand papers like [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0307199) for example, which makes heavy use of fibre bundles and gauge connections to represent gauge fields, I am looking for a nice introduction to this topic.

The only thing I have read so far is the corresponding chapter 15 of Roger Penrose's "Road to Reality".

I do not want to read a whole book, I am rather thinking about an appropriate introductory paper, lecture notes, or a tutorial.

Comment: I have noted that [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/142887/36639) question is related and looks similar, but the answers do not contain what I am looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the definition of a fiber bundle and some examples on pp 376-379 of Hatcher's [online book](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html) *Algebraic Topology*. You might also consult "Fiber Bundles," chapter 4 of *Lecture Notes in Algebraic Topology*, by Davis-Kirk. A fast introduction to connections and curvature can be found [here](http://php.indiana.edu/~pkirk/papers/gauge.pdf). In the case of surfaces, chapter 3 of [these](http://www.math.u-psud.fr/~labourie/preprints/pdf/surfaces.pdf) lecture notes might be useful to you.

Answer (score 5):

for fiber bundles,you may look into novikov's modern geometry [part 2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387961623). it gives nice explanation and a good place to do learn some "real geometry"

Comment: Thanks for this hint, I hope you do not mind that I inserted a link to the book.

Answer (score 2):

For a 'physicsy' viewpoint, checkout ["Geometry of Physics"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107602602) by Frankel.

Comment: Thanks, this looks nice too.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know what are gauge connections. However for connections on bundles, a "lecture note" reference is J.-L. Koszul's [Lectures on Fibre Bundles and Differential Geometry](http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~publ/ln/tifr20.pdf).

Comment: The term "gauge connection" is not correct. Physicists use the term "gauge field" to denote a connection on a principal bundle. In fact, they usually denote by "gauge field" the local pull-back to the base of the connection one-form. A gauge transformation would be nothing but a right action of the Lie group of the bundle (assuming the transition functions act on the left).