# Path to understand the maths behind contemporary Physics.

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-physics, book-recommendation

I am a physicist but I do really love maths and I would like to learn and have a deep understanding of the maths used in theoretical physics, just for leisure, in my free time.

I know there is a book called "*The geometry of Physics*", by Frankel, which deals with many results and gives the proofs, but I wonder if you know a more "mathematician" way to learn things such as differential geometry, algebraic topology, the connection group-manifold. The knowledge of QM and of the physical part I think I have it.

Comment: Roger Penrose's book [The Road to Reality](http://www.amazon.com/The-Road-Reality-Complete-Universe/dp/0679776311) is worth looking at.

Comment: Yes, I know it, but I want a rigorous (although slower) treatment. Thank you for your answer, @TonyK.

Comment: Possibly related: [Very *mathematical* general physics book](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/950672/very-mathematical-general-physics-book/951446#951446)

Comment: Thank you very much, @MassimoOrtolano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Nakahara's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0750306068) covers a lot of ground and is an overall very nicely written book. In terms of a mathematician's treatment, I recommend looking over Frankel or Nakahara, picking out topics that you're interested in, and look up resource recommendation for each topic. To get you started, some things (in my opinion) any self-respecting physicist should have a grasp of are:

For general mathematical maturity, as well as topological aspects of physical systems (e.g. field theories), you need to get acquainted with topology:

- Point-set topology - There's a number of Math SE threads on this, for example [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7520/best-book-for-topology)
- Algebraic Topology - For these, [Hatcher's book](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html) is a standard and well-motivated treatment. Also see this [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84409/best-algebraic-topology-book-alternative-to-allen-hatcher-free-book)

  - homology
  - cohomology - usually De Rham cohomology is what a physicist should be comfortable with
  - homotopy

The setting of most physical theories (e.g. GR & QFTs in general backgrounds) is some smooth manifold, you need to get acquinted with basic differential geometry.

- Differentiable manifolds - definition of real and complex manifolds, vectors & forms & tensors, integration of forms
- (pseudo) Riemannian geometry - metrics, connections, curvature.

For these see [this Math SE thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13575/teaching-myself-differential-topology-and-differential-geometry). I personally enjoy the two books by Lee.

Classical and quantum gauge theories are described by bundles associated to principal bundles of the symmetry group, we need

- Fibre bundles
- Connections over fibre bundles

For these, see [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142887/reference-request-vector-bundles-and-line-bundles-etc?lq=1).

Again I think this is the **basics** of what every theoretical physicist should familiarize themselves with, and to have a decent grasp of basic theories in modern physics. Again Nakahara is the place to start, and a good reference to come back to for summaries.

Comment: Thank you very much, @bechira. Beginning with specific topics is what I was thinking because I want to learn from the basics, with the proofs of the results, and more slowly, yes, but also enjoying the path. I suppose I will begin with point set topology, I will check what you have said. I work in an applied field of physics and I don't know many of the references, but the two books by Lee for diff geo I have read they are great. I think the study of these things in my free time will work as a pleasure and for a deeper knowledge in general that is something that always pay you back.